# create bilingual language site with drupal 6

Tags: 6

i want to build a multi-language site (Chinese and English). From the documentation, I know I should install the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module, so i installed it, but there are some parts on my site that are not translated.

1. There are some parts as the following in every page (the Chinese version):

   ```
   <h1><a href="<?php print $base_path ?>" title="<?php print t('Home') ?>">测试公司</a></h1>
   ```

How do I translate *测试公司* when English is the set language?

1. On every page's top right part, there are some parts as the following:

   ```
   <div id="topnav"> 
     <a href="#" onclick="return setHomepage();">设为首页 |</a><a href="#" onclick="return addCookie();">&nbsp;添加收藏  |</a><a href="http://example.com/" class="zh">&nbsp;简体中文</a><a href="http://example.com/en" class="en">&nbsp;English</a>
   </div>
   ```

How do I translate *设为首页*, *添加收藏* and  *简体中文* to English, when the user access http://example.com/en?

I know I can put that content in a block, then translate it, but it's too weird.

Is there a simple way to get that?

**ps:**  why this one that i can't translate(english-->chinese)? the code is used to alter the conntact form . `$form['mail'] = array( '#title' => t('E-mail'), '#type' => 'textfield', .` when i searched the `E-mail` in the translate interface, i can't find it,but  when i changed `E-mail` to `test`. then i can search it. why? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the [t](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6) function on all text if you want translate it directly throw the admin panel.

Comment: how to use the t function .could you make me an example. thank you

Comment: You've many examples and better explanation in the link I give you for t function. (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)

Comment: Just a side note: `t()` is not used to translate from Chinese to English, but it is used to translate a string in English in the language set for the page, or for the user. If I pass a string in Chinese to `t()`, the function will return the exact same string it got as argument.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you can use the third parameter to tell that your string is Chinese and you can translate it in English as well.

Comment: No, you cannot. The source language is always English or, to be more precise, American English. The parameter you are referring to is described as (Drupal 6 documentation): "`$langcode` Optional language code to translate to a language other than what is used to display the page." It's the language to which the string is translated, not the language from which the string is translated.

Comment: yvan ,how to write the third parameter. when the language is Chinese or when the language is english. the $language object doesn't has an attribute of $langcode. thank you.

Comment: kiamlaluno, why this one can't translate? the code is used to alter the conntact form . $form['mail'] = array(  
 '#title' => t('E-mail'),  
'#type' => 'textfield',  .  i searched the E-mail in the translate interface, i can't find it, when i change to test. then i can search it. why? thank you.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was thinking that if you specify the language code in third parameter Drupal will add to in to language code to translate. You're right.

Comment: @runeveryday You string appear for translation only if she appears one time on the foreign language. For it, you should see E-Mail in your Chinese version to have access to the translation.

Comment: @runeveryday When you use `t("E-mail")` you are translating from English, which is what the function is for; to translate from another language to English, `t()` is not the function to use.

Comment: kiamlaluno, i know, i want to translate E-mail to chinese, when i searched the E-mail in the translate interface, i can't find it,but when i changed t("E-mail") to t("test"). then i can search it. why? thank you.